# Mixing templates with std::enable_if_t and specialisation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Edit: done a rewrite of the provided code from feedback to help illustrate the issue

Say I have a method `template<T> do_foo(T)` and that I use it purely using `std::enable_if` to define return values

This allows me to write signatures for it such as

```
// templates_top.h

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int> do_foo(T bb)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I can also put in more definitions for `do_foo` further down the line - `templates_top.h` doesn't need to have fwd declarations for everything that could go into `do_foo` - what ever invokes `do_foo` just has to.

Now say I have a couple of classes for which the implementation of `do_foo` would ideally *not* be in a header

```
// templates_a.h
#include "./templates_top.h"
#include "./templates_b.h"

class LocalTypeA { 
  public:
    LocalTypeB* internal_;
};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, LocalTypeA>::value, int> do_foo(T bb)
{
    // Some detailed business logic 
    // With recursive do_foo for member
    return do_foo<LocalTypeB>(*(bb.internal_));
}

// templates_b.h
#include "templates_top.h"

class LocalTypeB { 
    public: 
        bool the_val = false;
};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, LocalTypeB>::value, int> do_foo(T bb)
{
    // Some detailed business logic here 
    // specific to LocalTypeB that ideally isn't in a header
    // Also not that do_foo is called recursively for the std::is_fundamental type
    return do_foo<bool>(bb.the_val);
}
```

All that works fine when its all in the header. But now - we want to move that complex business logic out of the headers.

We can't fully-specialise it like `template<> do_foo(LocalTypeB)` as there is no generic implementation `template<typename T> do_foo(T)`. If we make that generic one - then the `std::is_fundamental` overload becomes ambiguous.

Is there a way for me to write this scenario so that

- `templates_top.h` preserves its ignorance of `LocalTypeA/B` and its use of `std::is_fundamental`
- Allowing the overloads for `LocalTypeA/B` to moved to their own respective impl files, and still resolve the `std::enable_if` signatured functions

FWIW - my target C++ standard is C++11, but I'm guessing features from C++14/17 may make this possible, so they are good too.

Worth stating - this is a fairly big simplification of a real problem that I've had some trouble explaining - I'm looking more for ways to solve the heart of the type conflict on a much larger scale.

Code sample [here](https://gist.github.com/ALTinners/24f61a5e0c015c523eafc2daf640de6f) - compile as `g++ main_a.cpp` or `g++ main_b.cpp`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: btw don't you want to have the order of `T` and `R` swapped to enable deduction for `T` ?

Comment: This is a _very_ simplified example of the problem I am actually trying to solve - where there are multiple pairs of template args linked by `struct`s with returning `std::true/false_type`    @idclev463035818 https://gist.github.com/ALTinners/4650f9ae75f27e5e81c8fc3f8e693b44 for a minimal - its literally just the 3 blocks in a row though. I'm trying to find some way for them all to coexist

Comment: @AndrewLipscomb go to https://godbolt.org/ and write there a code which reproduces your problem, then create a link and provide in question. Then it will be clear what is the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Most probably there are to different specialization which can be reach by converting some argument it different way. You have to show how this template is used.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/PBmxKT

Comment: Here is "fixed" version https://godbolt.org/z/4ifZB2 bu we still do not know why first `do_foo` is needed so probably this doesn't help you. You have to show how template supposed to be used for different types, so it is clear why you need specializations.

Comment: @MarekR sorry - not the solution I'm looking for. This is a _very_ distilled version of the actual problem.  Essentially - multiply the `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<R, std::string>::value, R>` for around 100+ individual types with more coming in each week. The `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<R, std::string>::value, R>` one would need to exclude all of those types. It also don't necessarily go 1-for-1 with types. For example we have one that looks like `std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<R>::value, R>`. I'm not sure how to expand the question in a readable way without additional complexity

Comment: I know that you could basically add in a struct that had a `true_type` for all the types we expected to use - and `false_type` for everything that is not considerable - but thats adding more code in the headers. I'm trying to essentially get code _out_ of headers to improve compilation time

Comment: For context (that might be worth putting into the question) - this is for translating dynamic data from scripted languages down via C++ into ROS Message classes - which are very static. Essentially each recognisable structure will get serialised into ROS messages - and there are a lot of messages. ROS messages can also be recursively added into each other as members - this parsing library also works with being able to deal with dynamic member encoding

Comment: If you focus your question on how this template supposed to be used, I'm sure you will receive answer faster.

Comment: @MarekR  rewrote the question to try to emphasise what I am trying to accomplish here. Would love a second look - again if what I am trying to do isn't clear please say

Answer (score 2):

Functions cannot be partially specialized.

SFINAE can indeed be used to discard overload.

It seems that tag dispatching is more appropriate here:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

template <typename T>
auto do_foo(Tag<bool>, T data)
{
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
void do_foo(Tag<void>, T data) = delete;

// ...

template <typename R, typename R>
auto do_foo(T data) -> decltype(do_foo(Tag<R>{}, data))
{
    return do_foo(Tag<R>{}, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm trying to make this work for a better code example I'm writing up and will edit the q when done with work today. [This](https://gist.github.com/ALTinners/3780552ed3cf243dcac64ef09abf91bf) is what I have so far - works fine for everything-in-headers, but now I want to fully specialise for some overloads and move impl into impl files. That's where I'm hitting issues - full specialisation alongside `std::enable_if_t` . Maybe check back later on for a better explained issue

Comment: Fully specialization should works, but return type should not be `auto`. I suggest to just add (non-template) overload instead, like: `char do_foo(Tag<int>, double);`

Comment: Updated the question by a fair margin to try to better explain what I am trying to accomplish. Had a go with tag based overloads but still couldn't find a way to get everything out of the headers - I'm still missing something

Comment: Are all your used types known? if not, you need type erasure to allow to move implementation in cpp.